# Webform default value fallback

Tags: webforms, tokens

Is it possible to have a fallback value when using tokens in a webform? I mean if a token cannot get evaluated, then the fallback value will be taken.
For example I get a default value from URL. If the specified query parameter is not there, I would like to set a literal default value. How can I achieve this?
The contributed module "Token OR" could do this, but it does not work together with Webform.